# prev and next button with text in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

in JQgrid prev and next button are showing with arrow images, what I want is to show prev and next buttons with text "PREV" and "NEXT" written on them instead of arrows.I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. I am newbie and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by adding some **JS** in **loadComplete** like following:

```
loadComplete: function () {
            $('#prev_grid-pager span').removeClass().text('PREV');
            $('#next_grid-pager span').removeClass().text('NEXT');
        }
```